# Defining Ord instance for own datatype

Tags: haskell, instance

Being new to Haskell I am having trouble to get an Order instance implemented for my datatype,
namely:

```
data Polynom = Polynom ([Double])
deriving Show   
p0 = Polynom([3.9,4.2,2.7])
p1 = Polynom([0.0,0.2,-3.6,9.4])
```

Polynomes are being a list of doubles, where i.e. `p0 = 2.7x² + 4.2x + 3.9`. My problem is that I just couldn't figure out the correct syntax for declaring the various if-cases, starting something like:

```
instance Ord Polynom where
realLength(a) > realLength(b) = a > b
       where if realLength(a)) == realLength(b) = compare lastElement(a) lastElement(b)
```

I know this is a really bad pseudo-code, but I hope you get the idea.

I would really appreciate any hints on how to get started, I think I can figure out the different cases myself!

Edit:
Figured `instance Eq` could be something like that, but compiler does not accept it.

```
instance Eq Polynom where
(realPolynom a) == (realPolynom b) = (Polynom a) == (Polynom b)
```

Code for `realPolynom`:

```
realPolynom :: Polynom -> Polynom
realPolynom (Polynom(m:ns)) 
| m==0.0 = realPolynom (Polynom(ns))
| otherwise = Polynom(m:ns)
```

Answer (score 3):

You may be looking for

```
instance Ord Polynom where
  compare (Polynom p) (Polynom q) = compare (length p, reverse p) (length q, reverse q)
```

this compares polynomials first by length (degree). When lengths coincide, coefficients are compared.

Note that this assumes the first coefficient (last in the list) of a polynomial is non-null. That is, `Polynomial [0,1,0]` is greater than`Polynomial [0,2]` according to this ordering. You may wish to add a `dropWhile (==0)` to cope with this.

Comment: Brilliant! Wouldnt have thought there is such an easy solution. Yes I thought about that problem, but i felt a had to write a function dropping the zeros from the end. Still: compiler states there is no instace (Eq, Polynom) which I thought would be automaticly generated

Comment: @Krismu just add `deriving (Show, Eq)` after the datatype declaration.